# VideoJS: fetches old segments during a live stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, http-streaming, hls.js

During a livestream event several of our customers had playback issue and checking the logs we found below warning was thrown

```
VIDEOJS:,WARN:,Problem encountered with playlist 2-index_133.m3u8. 
Excessive main segment downloading detected. Switching to playlist 0-index_131.m3u8.
```

and further looking into the CDN logs we found just before above warning player fetched old segments that were already fetched before, most of the cases it is the first segment in that playlist window (we maintained a playlist size of 10 segments, 6s long each)

For example, in table below for user1 at `9:31:19 AM` segment `index_131_13200326` was fetched and at `9:31:20 AM` an old segment `index_133_13200317` was fetched.

What can trigger such behavior?

[image: player requests from different users]